# NHibernate: projection and reference type properties

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I'm using nHibernate and I've 3 mapped classes - A, B, C. Class A looks as the following:

```
public class A
{
 public virtual string StringProp1 { get; set; }
 public virtual string StringProp2 { get; set; }
 public virtual B BProp { get; set; }
 public virtual C CProp { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine, but what I would like to do is some optimization.  My purpose is to have a possibility to dynamically specify which properties should be loaded (from DB). So I can't just mark some properties as lazy in the mapping. The way I think it should work is the following:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<A>();
criteria.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
.Add(Projections.Property("StringProp1"), "StringProp1")
.Add(Projections.Property("BProp"), "BProp"));
criteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<A>());
return criteria.List<A>();
```

But this doesn't work for reference type property(like BProp), even if I'll add an alias to the criteria. I'm getting 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' exception on the last line.

If I remove line which adds projection of BProp, this works and returns me instance of A class where only StrinProp1 is filled with value. But I want to have corresponding instance of B class loaded into BProp as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like the right way to do things. If you're trying to eager-load BProp, you should be doing something like:

```
criteria.SetFetchMode("BProp", SetFetchMode.Eager);
```

Comment: I'd like to load BProp and StringProp1 properties, but not CProp and StringProp2 (in order to make result SQL statement simpler and faster). I dont think FetchMode is what I'm looking for.